# Accessing Promoted Property from within a map

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2009

I am trying to correlate an orchestration based on part of a received file location name and the date received. I have the receive port with an inbound map that assigns the date, but I cannot figure out out to access the promoted property for the receive location (which I have promoted).

Is there any way to access this info? Xpath? C# functoid?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Literally answering your question, yes, there is a [C# functoid](http://contextaccessor.codeplex.com) that allows access to the context properties from within a map.

However, if I understand your question correctly, you have an orchestration that sends a request message and is asynchronously waiting for a correlated response. I also understand that you would like all messages received from a specific *Receive Location* at a certain date to be routed back to the appropriate orchestration.

For this, you do not need to access promoted properties from within a map. All you have to do is initialize an appropriate *Correlation* when sending the message and have the properties specified in the *Correlation Set* promoted by the incoming *Receive Pipeline*.

For this to make sense, obviously, you would need to restrict the date to an acceptable range, with precision to a day, a hour-range or even a minute-range. Anything below that would run the risk of not being able to correlate the response to the appropriate time.

If you have some degree of control on the particular system that produces the response, using a GUID for the correlated property is probably the simplest approach.

Comment: +1 Correlation Set is the proper way to solve this. I prefer using a GUID for the property the correlation is based on. BTW: Why did you turn your answer into a Community Wiki?

Comment: Usually, I turn answers that have already been accepted as Community Wiki, so that they could be improved upon, since there's no way for an accepted answer to revert to not-accepted-yet. I guess I was not thinking clearly in this particular case :-)